# Do PHP child processes use the same Mysqli Connection Pool?

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection, fork

This is what the PHP Documentation has to say on Connection Pooling:

> The mysqli extension supports persistent database connections, which are a special kind of pooled connections.

and

> Every PHP process is using its own Mysqli connection pool.

But do child processes (after a `fork()`) share the same connection pool?

Therefore, is a permanent database connection avoiding that one child closes another child's connection?

Comment: *(reference)* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Answer (score 0):

Read [this chapter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php) about mysqli and persistent connections on the official PHP site. Normally a forked child process will share its parents' file-descriptors (which sockets are) so theoretically the answer is yes.

> Therefore, is a permanent database connection a solution for the Server has gone away problem?

You will have to try, this error can happen under a variety of circumstances.

Comment: My children are each opening a permanent connection — so if they use the same pool, most of them should use the same connection and not close any — right?

Comment: Eventually a child might be forced to close a broken socket but normally your child processes can pool on the same group of sockets.